# PHP: Overwriting of static methods does not work as expected

Tags: php, class, inheritance, static

I have two php classes: TestUK and TestFR, which extends TestUK.

Both classes are used to generate requests to two different domains. But something is going wrong with the inheritence, and I fail to understand why.

I have one method named "get_domain", which is overwritten to get the domain that should actually be used. If I call it directly via `TestFR::get_domain()`, i receive the expected result. But if I call a method that is not overwritten by TestFR, but which uses `self::get_domain()`, I receive the wrong domain.

If I simply copy-and-paste the method do_stuff from TestUK to TestFR, then I get the expected result. But copy-pasting identical (!) code is just what I was trying to avoid.

What is the reason for this? I do not have that much experience with class inheritence in PHP, but I would have expected this to work without problems. Or is my approch completely flawed?

```
<?php
class TestUK {

    const DOMAIN_UK = 'http://www.domain.co.uk';
    const DOMAIN_FR = 'http://www.domain.fr';

    static function get_domain(){
        return self::DOMAIN_UK;
    }

    static function do_stuff(){
        echo self::get_domain();
    }

}

class TestFR extends TestUK {

    static function get_domain(){
        return self::DOMAIN_FR;
    }

}

// Works as intended:
// Expected and actual output: http://www.domain.fr
echo TestFR::get_domain();

// Does NOT work as intendes:
// Expected Output: http://www.domain.fr
// Actual Output:   http://www.domain.co.uk
TestFR::do_stuff();
?>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because the keyword `self` refers to the class where it appears in, not to the class on which the method was called. For the latter functionality you will have to use [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) with the `static` keyword:

```
static function do_stuff(){
    echo static::get_domain();
}
```

That said, this code smells really bad. Why is everything `static` and not simply an instance method? Why is `TestFR` extending `TestUK` instead of both extending an abstract base class `Test`?

It would be **much** better to convert everything to non-static methods, and as a bonus your problem would immediately disappear.

Comment: Did convert it now to non-static. I realize it is the better approach, it was some old code not originally meant to use multiple domains. Both solutions (using "static" and converting classes to non-static) worked. It was really bugging me what was actually causing the problems here.

Answer (score 1):

call it like (if you are using php >= 5.3

```
static::get_domain();
```